# Can Adding Namespace to my current website, will give me any performance or flexibility Gain?

Tags: c#, namespaces

We have quite Large Web Based System, which is recently converted from Website to WebApplication, when it was an Website we not have any classes marked under the standard MyCompany.UI Namespace, now I am planning to move all the classes under the namespace, will I gain anything with doing that?

Thanks,
Manoj

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using namespaces will (should) help you organize your code and separate your code from other people's stuff without having to create elaborate complicated class names.  Namespaces will not provide you with any performance advantages - the computer has to do the same work regardless of what the class is called.

Answer (score 2):

Using namespaces won't improve your code's performance.  They just help organize your code into sections.